# How to send a value from a LinkButton to the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linkbutton

I have many LinkButton such as:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" onclick="cmdCancellaComunicazione_Click">X</asp:LinkButton>
```

they call the same server method, `cmdCancellaComunicazione_Click`. but I need to distinguish them (passing to the server, for example, a value).

How can I do it? I know there is CommandArgument, but I can't set to it a value such as <%= myValue %>

Comment: set the commandargument with databinding, e.g. `<%# myvalue %>`.  You of course need to call BindData to make it bind.  But the point is, you can't use `<%= %>` for a server control value.

Comment: Have you tried google? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551353/how-to-verify-which-linkbutton-is-clicked-in-asp-net-on-a-page-load

Comment: @mybrave: my question is different!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has no `ID` specified on your `LinkButton` which seems odd.

You should be able to assign the `CommandArgument` server side with:

```
yourLinkButton.CommandArgument = yourValue;
```

And then it will be read it server side in your `OnClick` handler.

```
 protected void cmdCancellaComunicazione_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
     if (btn.CommandArgument.Equals(something here))
     {
          // do something
     }
     else
     {
          // do something else
     }
 }
```

Is this being created in a grid or something that is being bound?  If so I would implement the `OnDataBinding` event for the `LinkButton` like:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="yourLinkButton"
    runat="server" OnDataBinding="yourLinkButton_DataBinding"
    onclick="cmdCancellaComunicazione_Click">X</asp:LinkButton>
```

Server side code (I try to avoid inline code whenever possible):

```
protected void protected void lblID_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
    btn.CommandArgument = yourValue;
}
```

Is there something more to your scenario that you have not included in your question?

Comment: This is a great solution man! But how can I pass a value trought OnDataBinding? I mean, if I have the link button inside a foreach, I'd like to put a progressive number to it, such as `btn.CommandArgument = "value" + counter;`

Comment: Anyway, where the CommandArgument value is stored? Only on Server Side I think? That's nice, so a user can't see which value have it, for example!

Comment: @markzzz It's pretty easy to make a counter in the `OnDataBinding`, just add a global variable to your page class and then increment it each time the `OnDataBinding` event is triggered.  The `CommandArguement` will be stored in the `ViewState`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sender argument of the event-handler. Cast it to `LinkButton`:

```
protected void cmdCancellaComunicazione_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   LinkButton lbtn = (LinkButton) sender;
}
```

Then you can use it's [`CommandName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandname.aspx), [`ID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id.aspx) or [`Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.text.aspx) to distinguish.

Comment: I have the same problem: can't set an id using custom variables <%= %> : I'm inside a for each...

Comment: @markzzz: Where do you use a `foreach` on the aspx markup? Why don't you use a webdatabound control like GridView or Repeater and the codebehind?

Answer (score 0):

In your method, you can cast the `sender` to a `LinkButton` and inspect the value there.

Answer (score 0):

`OnCommand` would be a good option here.

```
protected void ButtonCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string theCommand = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
}
```

Just add the `OnCommand` and `CommandArgument` to the `LinkButton`.

```
<asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" Text="The Text" OnCommand="ButtonCommand" CommandArgument="YourInfo" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: The same. Can't use <%= %>

Comment: Please show how you are building your repeater / loop then, and how you are binding it.

Comment: i.e if this was a repeater you could use `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TheField") %>'`